# Angular | How to initially load data before the app is resolved?

Tags: angular, promise

I'm writing a web application using Angular.

Each time a user navigates to the site, the app must perform a few server calls *before* the app is ready.

I have tried to define a function that must be resolved in Routes:

```
{path: '', resolve: {data: AppService}, children: [
   {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},,
   {path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent},
   {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
   {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
]}
```

and in AppServices I have the following function:

```
  resolve(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('RESOLVING');
        resolve();
      }, 5000);

    })
  }
```

This does not work: The page a user navigates to is displayed before `resolve` is called.

**Question:** How can I define a function that must be resolved before the app is ready? This function must be called regardless of a user is navigating to `/` or `/foo` `/foo/bar` and must only be called the first time the user navigates to the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add to app providers:

```
{
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: startupServiceFactory,
        deps: [ Session ],
        multi: true,
    },
```

where:

```
export function startupServiceFactory(startupService: Session): Function {
    return () => startupService.initialize();
}
```

replace the startupService.initialize() to your method.
the deps contains any dependency your service has, can be omitted.

example:

```
 async initialize(): Promise<any> {
        try {
            if (!environment.production) {
                this.user = await this.service.init();
                this.role = this.user.role;
                this.lang = this.user.lang;
                this.translate.use(this.user.lang);
                this.registerLocale();
                this.navigate();
                return;
            }
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        } catch (err) {}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. The 'initialize' function must return a promise, right?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Much appreciated!

Comment: This will in invoked only once when application is initialized not Each time a user navigates to the site.

Comment: it will. The example above is autologin my users into my app in case their session is live. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canActivate gurard which can return a Observable of boolean on routes.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router }    from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(private router: Router) { }

      canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
            //Ajax call and other logic
            return Observable.of(true)
      }
    }



{path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
   {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},,
   {path: 'faq', component: FaqComponent},
   {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
   {path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
]}
```

Comment: This approach would work, but it looks a bit hacky to me. I don't think canActivate is build for this use case. I also think that canActivate is called each time route changes (might be wrong tho)

Comment: I think APP_INITIALIZER will not be invoked each time user navigates to site.